# iOS 6 bluetoothmanager pairing private api

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

I'm trying to communicate with a 3rd party bluetooth device from an iPhone 4s with iOS6, and using a bluetooth headset as an example.
After checking many guides and tutorials on the subject, I came to the following conclusions:

a -The most suitable way for me to make communication work is to use "IOS bluetoothManager private framework". (I don't need to upload it to app store)

b - The steps are:

1. Find the device
2. Get his info (address)
3. pair
4. communicate

c - Apparently there is no way to make it work :(

I based my app on this:  [Bluetooth and iOS – Use Bluetooth in your iPhone apps](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/#.VHsI4DGUeQg), and wrote my app based on it.

When I run it, the app finds the headset device

xcode output console:

```
2014-11-30 14:31:57.041 BluetoothNew[146:907] BTM: attaching to BTServer
2014-11-30 14:31:57.050 BluetoothNew[146:907] BTM: enabling device scanning
2014-11-30 14:32:00.451 BluetoothNew[146:907] BTM: found device "UA06XB-B" 20:14:05:12:7A:3B
2014-11-30 14:32:00.454 BluetoothNew[146:907] Name: UA06XB-B
Address: 20:14:05:12:7A:3B
MajorClass: 1024
MinorClass:4
Type:16
BatteryLevelSupport:0
```

When I try to pair to the device I get the following message in xcode console:

```
2014-11-30 14:32:04.686 BluetoothNew[146:907] BTM: setting pincode '0000' for device "UA06XB-B" 20:14:05:12:7A:3B
2014-11-30 14:32:04.688 BluetoothNew[146:907] BTM: connecting to device "UA06XB-B" 20:14:05:12:7A:3B
2014-11-30 14:32:07.303 BluetoothNew[146:907] BTM: attempting to connect to service 0x00000001 on device "UA06XB-B" 20:14:05:12:7A:3B
2014-11-30 14:32:07.938 BluetoothNew[146:907] BTM: connection to service 0x00000001 on device "UA06XB-B" 20:14:05:12:7A:3B failed with error 158
```

connection code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *labelText = cell.textLabel.text;

    BluetoothDevice *device =  [self.currentAvailableDevices objectForKey:labelText];
    BluetoothManager *btManager =   [[self bluetoothScanner]getBluetoothManager];
    [btManager setPincode:@"0000" forDevice:(device)];
    [btManager connectDevice:device];


    // I tried this way too with the same result

    //[device setPIN:@"0000"];
    //[device  connect];
    //NSLog(@"service supported: %d", [device isServiceSupported:0x00000001]);
}
```

What is the problem?
What is error 158?

Any help would be appreciated.

Slava.

Comment: Is there a reason you are looking at Private Headers and not the Core Bluetooth API introduced in iOS5+. The obvious reason is this is being built for a device pre iPhone 4S.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution. It worked for me.

```
BluetoothManager *btManager = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance];
[btManager setDevicePairingEnabled:true];
[btManager setConnectable:true];
[btManager setPincode:@"0000" forDevice:device];
[btManager connectDevice:device];
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this would help you,you can try with service tag 0x00002000

```
BluetoothManager *btManager =  [[self bluetoothScanner] bluetoothManager];
[btManager setDevicePairingEnabled:YES];
[btManager connectDevice:bluetoothDevice withServices:0x00002000];
```